# How to Solved ErrorException : Required @OA\PathItem() not found

Tags: laravel

How to fix following:

> ErrorException  : Required @OA\PathItem() not found

Anyone can help me to fix this issue, new to try using `"darkaonline/l5-swagger".`

Answer (score 3):

This error means the "paths" part is missing in your code I explain :

```
paths": {
    "/animals": {
        "get": {
            "tags": [
                "Animal"
            ],
```

Should appear in your **swagger.json** file. If it doesn't, it means you never declared any route. Create one like this :

```
/**
 * @OA\Delete(
 *     path="/animals/{animalId}",
 *     summary="Delete an Animal",
 *     tags={"Animal"},
 *     ...
 * )
 */
```

It's a delete route but you should create a simple GET ;)
Hope it helps !

Lord'

Answer (score 0):

```
vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Loggers/DefaultLogger.php:28
```

Get it in the description line:

```
trigger_error($message??null, $error_level);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I didn't have any annotations with paths. After adding an annotation with a path it got fixed. Example taken from the "darkaonline/l5-swagger" github

```
/**
 * Add a new pet to the store.
 *
 * @OA\Post(
 *     path="/pet",
 *     tags={"pet"},
 *     operationId="addPet",
 *     @OA\Response(
 *         response=405,
 *         description="Invalid input"
 *     ),
 *     security={
 *         {"petstore_auth": {"write:pets", "read:pets"}}
 *     },
 *     @OA\RequestBody(ref="#/components/requestBodies/Pet")
 * )
 */
```

If the error persist despite adding the annotation, try changing where you place the annotation (move it outside the class declaration etc.)